# Adding eigenvalues to a user input matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, linear-algebra

I'm trying to get the matrix to return whether the user inputted matrix is positive definite or not. This is what I've done and I've tried putting all the values elsewhere.

```
def def_int(*, input_msg, err_msg):
  while True:
    try:
      return int(input(input_msg))
    except:
      print(err_msg)

def get_row(*, columns, input_msg, err_msg):
  while True:
    s = input(input_msg)
    if len(list(s.split())) != columns:
      print(err_msg)
      continue

    row = []
    for s in s.split():
      try:
        val = float(s)
        row.append(val)
      except Exception:
        print(err_msg)
        continue
    return row

def get_matrix():
  rows = def_int(
    input_msg="Input number of rows in the matrix.",
    err_msg="Please insert an integer",
  )
  columns = def_int(
    input_msg="Input number of columns in the matrix. ",
    err_msg="Please insert an integer",
  )

  matrix = []
  for i in range(rows):
    row = get_row(
      columns=columns,
      input_msg=f"What is the {i}th row of your matrix? ",
      err_msg=f"Input doesn't work, must be {columns} floats separated by spaces",
    )
    matrix.append(row)
  return np.array(matrix)
  


def main():
  matrix = (get_matrix())
  if np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(get_matrix()) > 0):
    print("Positive Definite")
  elif np.all(np.linalg.eigvals(get_matrix()) < 0):
    print("Negative Definite")
  else:
    print("Error")
  print(matrix)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I tried to past the code relating to the eigenvalues everywhere but it didn't work.

Comment: You're calling `get_matrix()` multiple times